# Apache Karaf and Apache Commons Bundles

Tags: architecture, osgi, apache-karaf

Right so some really noob(this is my first deployment of a bundle to Karaf) questions for the Apache Karaf folks out there. I am deploying a bundle that uses a lot of the org.apache.commons.* bundles. When I deployed my bundle and then try to start it, Karaf threw a error about not finding org.apache.commons.pools for example. I did a bit of googling and ran the following:

```
osgi:install mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-pool
```

This installed the missing bundle and I hit the next one. While I understand that the required bundles are not installed into the OSGI container I have some questions that need clarification.

- From my understanding the bundle I am installing is using some sort of servicemix bundle. 
  So I want to know is this needed, cant I just add a org.apache.commons.pool bundle instead of a full servicemix bundle?
- When I am missing a bundle how can I find out which maven url to use. For example say I needed a foobar bundle how would I go about adding the bundle if I dont know the url? Right now I cant start my bundle due to package=org.apache.log not being found. So how would I know how to add this?
- Difference between a bundle and feature?

Hope the questions are clear enough. I am making headway with karaf just need to clarify these points.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not all the Java "jars" are OSGi compatible, they need to have the [OSGi bundle manifest](http://static.springsource.com/projects/dm-server/1.0.x/programmer-guide/html/ch08s05.html).

I follow this steps when I need to add a dependency from the console:

- Search the library at [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com/)
- Try to install it like this:

  install mvn:[group-id]/[artifact-id]/[version]
- If it's not an OSGi library then I search it at [SpringSource](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/). On this repository all the bundles are OSGi, but it's normal that they have outdated versions.
- My last option is to use the Karaf wrap deployer that let you deploy non-OSGi bundles. Check the [user guide](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-2.2.x/users-guide/deployer.html).

And about the features, a feature is just a set of bundles. Read [this post](http://trenaman.blogspot.com.es/2010/08/karafs-fabulous-features-and-what-you.html) for further details.

Comment: If you are using karaf run this from karaf console : bundle:install mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-lang/2.4_6